# MassTransit, consumer does not get activated unless the message is in a common library

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have a publisher library which simple sends a message , and a consumer library which just consumes messages.
These two are linked by a common library which contains a message called `T`. In this configuration everything works just fine.

Now If I go ahead and copy the T in each of the two, so I'm removing any link to the shared messages library, the consumer does not get triggerd, and I see a new queue named like my initial queue but with the suffix of `_skipped`

What do I need to configure in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit uses the fully-qualified class name as the message type. It is not a *shared library* thing, you need to ensure the namespace of the message on the producer side matches the namespace on the consumer side.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine it does not care about the shared library and it takes the type's fullname, but Is there any other way of working around this ? Can I for instance specify my own name ? For example if I want to make the message name something like like `service1-messageName`

Comment: The message name requirement is [clearly outlined in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html) and cannot be changed. Use the same namespace.